# why are touches (set) are passed instead of a touch in touchesBegan?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, touch

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

why is 'touches' not just 'touch' being passed for touchesBegan/Moved/Ended?

What's the meaning of them?

Answer (score 2):

That's because user may do a multiple taps (quickly) in which case you'll receive a set of multiple `NSTouch` objects.

A demonstration of this is the zooming effect when you double tap on a scroll (or image) view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can receive multiple touches, but they are disabled by default. In order to receive multiple touch events you must set the `multipleTouchEnabled` property of the corresponding view instance to `YES` and touch with 2 or more fingers.